# Timevis: Making variable text appear outside of box

Tags: r, date

Using his example code:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA),
  editable = TRUE
)
timevis(data)
```

His output when zooming in the name goes next to the box, whereas when I run his code it tries to fit all the name inside of the  box and hence Ranged Item will appear as Ran inside the Ranged Item box for example which is really annoying and I can't work out how to fit it!! whereas in his one ranged item will appear inside and just continue writing outside of the box.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be controlled with CSS `.vis-item .vis-item-overflow { overflow: visible; }`.

If you are using timevis for a Shiny app, the easiest way is to add the styling in the header. Alternatively you can also keep the styling in a separate file, normally in the `www` directory of the Shiny app. This is well documented.

For your example, here's how it would work:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
  id      = 1:4,
  content = c("Item one", "Item two",
              "Ranged item", "Item four"),
  start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11",
              "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
  end     = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA),
  editable = TRUE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .vis-item .vis-item-overflow { overflow: visible; }
    "))
  ),
  timevisOutput('timeline')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$timeline <- renderTimevis( timevis(data) )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks alot :), i'm doing it outside of shiny at the moment, how would I go about doing it then? I was thinking of doing a shiny interpretation of it at a later date but as i've never used shiny before wanted to get it functionality working outside. I'm not sure where I'd use the vis-item?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the help instruction to do it outside shiny:

```
tv = timevis(data)
style <- "
.vis-item .vis-item-overflow { overflow: visible; }
"

tv2 <- tagList(tags$style(style), tv)
htmltools::html_print(tv2)
```